# FireMonkey drawing with tPath does not fill the shape

Tags: drawing, firemonkey, shapes

I want to use a TPathData to draw shapes and fill them with an arbitrary color. I'm using the following code, at Button1Click, which I extracted from a sample at Embarcadero documentation:

```
procedure TformPathDrawing.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var path: TPathData;
begin
  Image1.Bitmap.Canvas.Fill.Color := TAlphaColorRec.Blue;
  path      := TPathData.Create;
  path.Data := 'M 01,00 L 02,01 L 01,02 L 00,01 L 01,00';
  Image1.Bitmap.Clear ($FFFFFF);
  Image1.Bitmap.Canvas.BeginScene;
  Image1.Bitmap.Canvas.FillPath (path, 200);
  Image1.Bitmap.Canvas.EndScene;
end;
```

When this code is executed, as expected, a rhomboid is rendered, but it is not filled up with the color set in the first command. Anyone know what is wrong? Thanks.

Comment: Opacity is a float value in the range 0..1, you have entered a value of 200!

Comment: Yes. I used Opacity = 1 with the same result. The Opacity = 200 is how appears in the Embarcadero's sample.

Comment: I believe you should set the Fill property after beginning the scene.

Comment: Scratch my last comment, just tried the examples myself, and everything works just fine. Including setting the Fill.Color to TAlphaColorRec.Blue. So I actually don't see whats wrong with your code. Which Delphi version are you using? Examples from here BTW: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/CodeExamples/Tokyo/en/FMXTCanvasFillFunctions_(Delphi)

Comment: Thanks Sherlock. My Delphi version is Berlin Update 2. I took the code from that Web page your'e pointing at. In the FillPath example, it adds a tEllipsis and a tRectangle, but in my case, I'm using a tPathData.

Comment: Correction: I set the TPathData with a SVG command.

Comment: Berlin here too, and your code works just fine for me... Had to blow up the polygon a bit, but it worked just fine. So...I'm baffled. Which windows version is this on?

Comment: @Sherlock. Would you mind to share the code you used? My Windows is 10 64 bits.

Comment: Also try to set ´Fill.Kind := TBrushKind.Solid´. When others can run the code without problems, there must be some values in your Bitmap.Canvas, that do not have their default values. You just need to find them.

Comment: @ppro: Code is in my answer.

Comment: Btw, you are leaking memory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follows code that works (in my case):

```
procedure TformPathDrawing.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
Image1.Bitmap.Canvas.Fill.Color := TAlphaColorRec.Blue;
path.Clear;
path.Data := 'M 01,00 L 02,01 L 01,02 L 00,01 L 01,00';
Image1.Bitmap.Canvas.BeginScene;
Image1.Bitmap.Canvas.FillPath (path, 1);
Image1.Bitmap.Canvas.EndScene;
end;
```

In my code, variable `path` is created outside the painting code. Since  `path.Data;` is additive, it is mandatory, before adding the current `path.Data;`, to place a `path.Clear;` statement, to clean out whatever remains into the point array. Hope this help other people.

Comment: Assigning a path leads to `TPathData.SetPathString()` which clears previous content internally (calls `FPathData.Clear;`), so your `path.Clear` is not required (in the code you show here, maybe it is different in your actual code)

Answer (score 1):

Because comments can't have code (at least not formatted). Here is my code, that works.

```
procedure TForm7.RadioButton6Click(Sender: TObject);
var path: TPathData;
begin
  Image1.Bitmap.Canvas.Fill.Color := TAlphaColorRec.Blue;
  Image1.Bitmap.Canvas.Stroke.Color := TAlphaColorRec.black;
  path      := TPathData.Create;
  try
    path.Data := 'M 01,00 L 20,01 L 10,20 L 00,10 L 01,00';
    Image1.Bitmap.Clear ($FFFFFF);
    Image1.Bitmap.Canvas.BeginScene;
    Image1.Bitmap.Canvas.FillPath (path, 200);
    Image1.Bitmap.Canvas.EndScene;
  finally
    path.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Note that the stroke color is set as well. That's the only difference I can make out here.

Comment: Thanks Sherlock. I take your answer as correct, although in my environment it does not work (wonder why). I will set properly all Fill and Stroke options and see what hapens.

Answer (score 1):

Here is right code. You can find another details in FMX.Objects.pas procedure TCustomPath.UpdateCurrent and other; or just Debug TPath visual component.

```
     {aPath - is vector path of image;
     aStretch - how to draw vector data - true - stretch draw, false = fit to bitmap
     aBitmap - must be created. In bitmap you should specify:
     Width, Height, Bitmap.Canvas.Fill.Color, Bitmap.Canvas.Stroke.Color
     and, if you need, another drawing stuff like Gradient, stroke thikness, 
     background texture) }

procedure TForm1.DrawVectorPath(const aPath: string; aBitmap: TBitmap; aStretch: boolean);
var
  vPath: TPathData;
  R: TRectF;
begin
  Assert(aBitmap <> nil);
  vPath := TPathData.Create;
  try
    vPath.Data := aPath;
    aBitmap.Clear($FFFFFF);
    if aStretch then
    begin
      R := vPath.GetBounds;
      vPath.Translate(-R.Left, -R.Top);
      vPath.Scale(aBitmap.Width / R.Width, aBitmap.Height / R.Height);
    end
    else // Fit image
    begin
      R := TRect.Create(0, 0, aBitmap.Width, aBitmap.Height);
      vPath.FitToRect(R);
    end;

    aBitmap.Canvas.BeginScene;
    aBitmap.Canvas.FillPath(vPath, 1);
    aBitmap.Canvas.DrawPath(vPath, 1);
    aBitmap.Canvas.EndScene;
  finally
    vPath.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: It's your comments, so you should delete them - I can't. Please pay attention at line: aBitmap.Canvas.DrawPath(vPath, 1);  . With this ready to use proc I usually draw vector images. If you like it, please accept  it as answer (because previous Sherlock70's answer is incorrect and not work).

Comment: Yes your code works fine in this case, because you are creating the `tPathData` inside the painting code, wich is not may case (see question answer below).